# Stay on memory pool when I sending multiple transaction from bitcoin wallet

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet, transaction-fees, unconfirmed-transactions, mempool

I run the bitcoin client 0.17.1 on my ubuntu 18.04 desktop. I have some balance in my wallet. Also my client is fully synced.I have face the wallet conflict. When I send multiple transaction at once(without time gap). Happen two things.

1. Some transaction is confirmed and completed successfully
2. Some transaction is stay on the memory pool for a long time. And the status is show as `0/unconfirmed, in memory pool`

If I send transaction with some of time gap, no problems is existing. Also I mention that I already used `bumpfee` RPC. But transaction stay on the unconfirmed stage.

Note: I give the proper fee for every transaction

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is my transaction not getting confirmed and what can I do about it?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/9046/why-is-my-transaction-not-getting-confirmed-and-what-can-i-do-about-it)

Comment: No, It is not my answer. This answer is say about the transaction fee. But in my case, I give the transaction fee than standard fee rate.

Comment: How many transactions are you sending at the same time? How long is the "time gap".

Comment: Almost 10 seconds !

Comment: How many transactions are you creating?

Comment: Almost 12 transactions

Answer (score 1):

Bitcoin Core has locks in place that will stop multiple calls to build a transaction to be executed in parallel. Instead, they will be executed sequentially, as the lock gets relinquished by the previous call. So, the other thing that comes to mind is that there are limits to the ancestry set of transactions that may be submitted to the mempool at the same time.

Your own node's mempool will not accept more than 25 transactions or more than 101 kB in total transaction size that are chained/interdependent in some fashion. Your wallet will attempt to rebroadcast transactions to your own mempool every thirty minutes or so, so even when some of the ancestors of your transactions get confirmed, it may take a while for the others to be relayed to the network.

What you can do: If you're sending a very large number of transactions, e.g. more than 25 per block, you should split up your balance across a greater number of UTXOs, so that you can create a larger count of independent transactions.

Comment: Hi @Murch , Thanks for answering. I do not create 25 transactions. I only created approximately 12 transaction per block.

Comment: Are the transactions very large? Does your wallet have a very large number of unspents?

Comment: What is mean by transactions very large, Do you mean by very large amount...???

Comment: No, I'm talking about the data size of the transaction. Does it have a very large count of inputs?

Comment: No. It does not a large count of input

Comment: Also have any document is available to practically apply the greater number of UTXO for increase increase the count of transaction...??

Comment: Splitting your balance into more UTXO would only help if you have a large balance. Are you perhaps running out of confirmed funds and then start creating transactions that spend incoming funds sent from third parties? And those parent transactions take a long time to confirm?

Comment: Hey. I try bumpfee RPC. It show the error like "Error: The transaction was rejected: txn-mempool-conflict (code 18)".